# bust down -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Example with a context:

> I heard a new song at the tavern the other day. Something about gin and wild women.
>   How'd it go?
>   Oh, I don't remember. I stuck five nickels in the box to hear it again and the thing **busted down**. You know me, I couldn't carry a tune in a bushel basket.

What does *busted down* mean? Something like *broke down*, I presume?

Comment: According to Longman dictionary it means that: 'to break something'

Comment: Consulted the ['answerable with dictionary'](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/466/policy-for-questions-that-are-entirely-answerable-with-a-dictionary) meta; _Longman_ only defines the contextual example, by cursorily equating to another single word. The question asked for an explanation of a slang term, and in this case, the word has both nuanced connotation and denotation which is not conveyed by that dictionary answer. Particularly with slang terms, I think it important for ELL to be exposed to explanation by native speakers, because its meaning will not be found in a dictionary.

Comment: Apologies, but another point perhaps worth mentioning: In the 'test question' cited in the original proposal on that meta, it was asked "what does X mean _in this context_," whereupon it became apparent it was a single sense of a dictionary definition. In asking about (esp.) a slang term, an example provides clarification of their current understanding, as a point of departure for answering. Particularly in the case of undocumented wordage, I think it would be well to err toward elucidating the fuller scope of meaning, in assuming that to be implied in asking about the definition generally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's generally synonymous with *break down*...in many of its forms, interestingly. It's extremely difficult to define, but here are some general hints about its usage, and a few examples.

The word *busted* is much more informal, though since it is used in this way fairly infrequently, it would be more accurate to call it slang. In most of its usages, *busted* is a very "blue collar" word, of the working class or dispossessed. To be honest it's fairly uncommon, and even a little "forced" in its slang (the word *busted* being too informal for most situations).

*Busted* is also much more emphatic, so something in a state of being *busted down* is in much greater distress/will be harder or take longer to recover from, or may be "stuck that way." For instance, to say a person's "broke down" usually means an unexpected delay caused by something less than catastrophic. But to be "busted down" in a particular place means things have gone seriously wrong and you may be stuck there. This is probably the meaning of the Doobie Brothers' song *Busted Down Around O'Connelly Corners*, or the similar phrase in Janis Joplin's *Me & Bobby McGee*: "Busted flat in Baton Rouge."

To bust down can also mean something like "smash down," or to demolish violently. One might say "The police busted down the door in a drug raid." And the Pearl Jam song *State of Love and Trust* contains the lyrics "State of love and trust/as I busted down the pretext/sin still plays and preaches/but to have an empty court." This song conveys general hopelessness, and the "pretexts" refer to assumptions or conditions in life that he tore down.

*Busted down* also has an idiosyncratic definition, meaning a demotion in rank. "The sargeant was busted down to a private for his misconduct."